# Including Custom Fields & static text in the_content in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I am editing a Custom Post Type template, and am using custom fields to enter info into a meta box to be included on the page, as well as include some static default text on all the pages.

I basically need to "chunk" together the post info in the_content along with the static text and some meta box info. Here's what I want:

- the_content
- static text
- meta box 1
- more static text
- meta box 2
- end of the _content

I have plugins that add social buttons before the_content and a signature after the_content so I am trying to figure out how to get all my custom stuff sandwiched in between those.

If I just add the meta boxes i nthe template, they display outside of the_content and the plugins display in unwanted places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out on my own. The solution: using functions.php and add_filter, I had to create a new function to create the default content, and it works great.

here's the general code for anyone interested:

```
function custom_post_type_default_content($content) {
global $post;
    if ($post->post_type == 'your-custom-post-type') {
    $content .= '<p> '. get_post_meta( $post->ID, "metabox-1-slug", true ).' 
    <br />
    <p> '. get_post_meta( $post->ID, "metabox-2-slug", true ).'</p>
    <p>YOUR TEXT HERE.</p>';
}
add_filter('the_content', 'custom_post_type_default_content', 0);
```

Note that the zero just near the end controls placement. I have a social media plugin that has a priority of "1", and to get the default content to appear above that I have to make this a priority of "0".

Also note the single apostrophes that open and close the code following `$content .=`

You basically add whatever you want between those apostrophes, and in this case I am pulling metabox info which have their own apostrophes containing code. It gets confusing!

In other words, your code should be `$content .='YOUR CUSTOM CONTENT'` and within those apostrophes, add your text, code, etc. The standalone metabox code is `'. get_post_meta( $post->ID, "metabox-1-slug", true ).'` which is nested inside where the YOUR CUSTOM CONTENT text is.

I am basically explaining this to myself, as these were the things that tripped me up so figured would explain them in detail to help someone else like me. Or me when I have to go look this up again!

Comment: Also, need to give credit to the person who helped me deduce my code syntax once I figured out I needed to do this in functions.php - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28663/including-inline-custom-fields-info-with-add-filter-in-functions-php

Comment: When using this, I had to return $content from the hook function, which is clearly indicated in the link in the comment, but not in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Post your single.php here or on pastebin along with the custom field names you're using (& where you want them) and I'll try to help you figure out what you want.

Comment: Much appreciated. My single.php is here (it's a custom post type single page, and using a child theme): http://pastebin.com/S7cLHZND

Comment: I'm using some custom fields throughout the body text template to auto-populate some paragraphs to make them specific to the page. I'm basically trying to get the Title, Subtitle, Featured Image, Price and some static text with inline meta box content to appear in the_content, in that order. I am also using a PayPal buy now button that gets placed in the main body content, and want that near the price.

Comment: Everything works fine, but the social media buttons and footer text plugin display everything below the meta box content I coded into the template. I tried doing it with functions.php but it didn't work; I probably did it incorrectly.

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a comment. Still, the comments contain some information that might be useful. @GeorgeC, please edit your question and add there the details you have put here. Then I think we can ask Matt to delete this answer, since it is what the community calls "Not an answer" (as said, it should be a comment). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Copy this code to your function.php file.

```
function content_function_update($content) {

    global $wp_query, $post;

    if ($post->post_type == 'your-custom-post-type') {

       $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;   
       $value1 = "your value 1";

       if($value1 !== '') {
          $content = $content . "<br>" . $value1 
       }
       else {
          $content = $content;
       }
    }

    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'content_function_update');
```

Add any custom content in variables and append it to $content variable.